# Как записать ширину блока через js

Tags: javascript

Почему у меня не работает ?

```
      var shirina;
    var leftMusic = left_music.offsetWidth;
    var rightMusic =  right_music.offsetWidth;
    var mainWidth = innerWidth;
    var best=document.getElementById("slide_music").offsetWidth;
 shirina = mainWidth-rightMusic-leftMusic;

    best=shirina;//должна получать ширину
```

Comment: Чему равно `innerWidth` на 4-ой строке? Являются ли `left_music` и `right_music` элементами DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы заработало, нужно задать для `leftMusic` и `rightMusic` блоки, для которых вычисляется эта самая ширина, например:

```
var leftMusic = document.getElementById('left-music');
var leftMusicWidth = leftMusic.offsetWidth;
```

При этом в файле с разметкой (с разширением `.html`) должен быть такой элемент:

```
<div id="left-music"></div>
```

Comment: Cпасибо, выручил )))

Comment: @Hungry ты можешь отметить ответ как полезный, нажав на треугольник вверх, чтобы другие пользователи могли находить полезные ответы и не тратить много времени на эти самые поиски)